# ndimage map_coordinates with masked arrays

Tags: python, scipy, ndimage

I am using ndimage to interpolate as follows:

```
ndimage.map_coordinates(input_data, coords, output, 2, prefilter=False)
```

Now, the problem is that I do not have valid measurements over my whole input data. So, I have a masked array which tells me which data points are valid. So, when doing the interpolation, I would like to only use pixels which are valid and also adjust the weightings accordingly (to ensure that the weights sum to 1).

However, I see that there is no easy way to do this. I was wondering if someone knows of a good way to do this or can point me to some library or code that I can use. I am coming from a C++ background, so still finding my way around python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to focus on the interpolation of data and then extract values from desired coordinates.  For 1D [splrep](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) and 2D [bisplrep](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html#scipy.interpolate.bisplrep) are the interpolation functions you need to check out ([A good overview](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html)).  Both of these functions can be weighted and provide fine tune control over the spline function you interpolate with.

Once you have filtered the data with the desired weights you can then determine the value at specified coordinates using.

```
ndimage.map_coordinates(input_data, coords, output, prefilter=True)
```

*note the `prefilter` key word argument is not needed as that is the default value*

Comment: The problem is that the interpolation data cannot handle masked arrays. Basically, I do not want it to use values which are not in the mask. However, I am not sure how to do that. I see some tickets now on scipy about this but I do not think this has been solved yet.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1682

Comment: A good way to exclude data would be to weight that data at 0.

Comment: Otherwise you could set unwanted values to `nan` and then possibly do something similar to stackoverflow.com/questions/6518811/interpolate-nan-values-in-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` to get interpolated values from arbitrary known data points. This example

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# data array
a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)).astype(float)
a[1, 1] = np.nan
print(a)
a = a.flatten()

# coordinate arrays
ii, jj = np.indices((3,3))
ij = np.stack((ii.flatten(), jj.flatten()), axis=1)

# filter out unknowns
mask = ~np.isnan(a)
a = a[mask]
ij = ij[mask]

# interpolate for the missing a[1, 1] element
res = griddata(ij, a, (1, 1), method='cubic')
print(res)
```

produces

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 3. nan  5.]
 [ 6.  7.  8.]]

4.000000157826586
```

Comment: I am not sure if this offers the requested control over weights, but they must sum to 1.